# Magento 2.3 unable to subscribe to newsletter

Tags: magento2, newsletter-subscriber

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 using php 7.3.15 and my Magneto 2 version is 2.3.3

Users that try to subscribe to our newsletter get the error: "Something went wrong while saving your subscription."
Same error occurs for both logged in users and not logged in users.

The wierd thing is that I can add them from the Admin Panel.

I have tried disabling all modules and our custom theme but it stil gives the same error. How do I fix this? Thanks.

From my var/logs I have received this

```
Trace: <pre>#1 Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber\Interceptor->subscribe('niklas.johns...') called at [vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php:156]
#2 Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction/Interceptor.php:24]
#3 Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#5 Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#6 Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [app/code/Aheadworks/Ca/Plugin/Controller/FrontActionPlugin.php:97]
#7 Aheadworks\Ca\Plugin\Controller\FrontActionPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor#00000000553be799000000004912d0c6#, &Closure#00000000553be7f7000000004912d0c6#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#8 Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#9 Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#), array(array('storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction/Interceptor.php:39]
#10 Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#, &Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction\Interceptor#00000000553be799000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:98]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#15 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#00000000553be5e5000000004912d0c6#, &Closure#00000000553be5cc000000004912d0c6#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]
#17 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#00000000553be5e5000000004912d0c6#, &Closure#00000000553be5cc000000004912d0c6#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#00000000553be408000000004912d0c6#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000553be467000000004912d0c6#) called at [index.php:40]

[2020-06-24 14:15:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"root/newsletter/manage/save/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"notification_update_customer_session_215"}} []
```

I've also tried this:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4325
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654994/magento-2-0-7-something-went-wrong-with-the-subscription/39721764

Comment: Can you remove Aheadworks modules from app/code and test it?

Comment: Thanks. Stil didn't work. Got the message 
`"2020-06-25 07:14:53] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"root/newsletter/manage/save/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"notification_update_customer_session_215"}} []

ain.CRITICAL: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at /var/www/html/root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:310)"} []
`
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Is Your Hosting Server Configured to sent emails. Only when there is a problem in sending emails the "Something went wrong" message will be displayed.

Try  **"Disable Email Communications"** to **yes** in Admin ( Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings > Disable Email Communications) and see if the error disappears.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm able to send and receive emails. Im just not able to subscribe.
I have tried to "Disable Email Communications" but without success :/